Does InfluxDB IOx builds any indexes itself on its tag-columns excepts for native index in parquet?
I am trying to dive into the sources of InfluxDB IOx which is a time series databases adopting Parquet as its file format.
As tags in InfluxDB are frequently considered as filtering conditoin, however they are stored as string-type columns as any other fields columns (which is meant to store sensor data).
I used InfluxDB 2.x in my project, so I am really curisou that whether InflxuDB IOx builds any indexes on thoes tag-columns? Except for thoes built by Parquet itself (a.k.a. PageIndex).
Really appreciate for any advice.
